# How to debug plugin source code in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, apple-mail

I am new to creating plug-ins for the Apple Mail Application, and I want to create Apple Mail plugin for OSX.

I have created a project under "Installer Plug-in" (Application Plug-in -> Installer Plug-in) in Xcode, but I can't debug that project like a simple iOS application.

Is it possible?

If it is possible then please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have find the solution of this problem.

Just follow the steps for debug the Plugins code in Xcode.

Step 1 = Go to Edit scheme in your Xcode and go to Edit scheme = >.
[image]

Step 2=Select Run and info tab from side window and select Executable Application from the drop down list (in my case Mail app from Application->Mail)

Keep your application running ant try to debug your Plugin source code....... its works for me fantastic..

Answer (score 2):

additional hint:

if you would debug a Xcode plugin, I found this:

Speedy37 commented on Sep 19, 2014:

With the default options you can't debug Xcode 6

Go to your debug options : Edit Scheme > Run > Options
and uncheck "Enable user interface debugging" (DebuggerUI can't debug itself)

After I do this I could debug Xcode plugIn, before it crashed.

Comment: disabling that option is the only way it would run. it kept crashing before.